# Running a docker container in EC2 with EC2 startup scripts

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I want such that when I launch an EC2 instance, it should automatically also run a docker container along with the launch.
I have given a startup script to do the same. But it is downloading the docker image but not running it.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install docker.io -y
sudo systemctl start docker
sudo systemctl enable docker
sudo apt  install awscli -y
aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-north-1 | sudo docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <password>
sudo docker pull <image_name>
sudo docker run -it -p 8080:8080 <image_name>
```

it is working totally fine till the last step
I have checked the bash script separately running it in terminal in an EC2 instance it works perfectly.

Comment: where did you put this startup script? In EC2's User Data?

Comment: yes, in ec2 user data

Comment: User Data are used just at the very first startup, so your approach will not work even fixing this issue.